# java.lang.IllegalStateException: open

Tags: java, mongodb

while I'm trying to read data from Mongodb I'm getting this Exception,

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: open
    at org.bson.util.Assertions.isTrue(Assertions.java:36)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.isMongosConnection(DBTCPConnector.java:369)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.isMongosConnection(Mongo.java:645)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._check(DBCursor.java:454)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:546)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:571)
    at com.calsoftlabs.mongo.client.impl.ReadingData.main(ReadingData.java:93)
```

MyCode

```
    public static DBCursor firstRecord(String ip) throws Exception {

        DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("client_ip", ip);

        DBCollection collection = getConnection();

        DBObject obj = new BasicDBObject("_id", 1);

        DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query).sort(obj).limit(1);

        mongo.close();

        return cursor;

    }
    DBCursor cursor = ReadingData.firstRecord(ip);

                    while (cursor.hasNext()) { 

                        cursor.next();

                        myList.add(new BasicDBObject("client_ip", (String) cursor.curr().get(
                                "client_ip")).append("timestamp",
                                (String) cursor.curr().get("timestamp")).append("total_traffic",
                                (String) cursor.curr().get("total_traffic")));

                    }
```

By using the above code I'm reading first record from set of records in Mongodb, but the line `cursor.hasNext()` throwing IllegalStateException. Please suggest me how to resolve this issue..

Comment: This `mongo.close();` is suspicious, you're trying to use the db after it...

Comment: see also https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-1251

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats why you call `mongo.close();` befor calling `cursor.hasNext())`.
Remove the `mongo.close();` from `firstRecord` and add it after your loop